# How can I go about getting this link from the youtube API to open in an Iframe in my page or at least open in a modal

Tags: php, youtube-api

Hi I am trying to get a list of videos with the youtube api and then open that into an iframe that is on my site.  The script below will retrieve a list of videos by keyword but It will only link to the page that the video is on and I would obviously like to open it into the iframe on my page.  Or at least open the youtube embed in a modal.  The `$watch` variable get the url but it comes back as https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoID&feature=youtube_gdata_player.  This will not open in an iframe even if I put it there manually.

Is there a way to parse this. Or return it with the full embed instead of `watch=tv`.  I also am not sure if there is a way to echo `target="video-frame"` in the `<a>` tag that is created.  Is there a different variable that I need to use to get the video url and is how would I write this to echo it as `<a href="" target="video-frame"></a>` for some reason when I do the server denies the page.

```
<?php
$feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/Keyword/';

$sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);

$counts = $sxml->children('http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/');
$total = $counts->totalResults;  
?>
<?php    
foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) {
  $media = $entry->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');

  $attrs = $media->group->player->attributes();
  $watch = $attrs['url']; 

  $yt = $media->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
  $attrs = $yt->duration->attributes();
  $length = $attrs['seconds']; 

  $gd = $entry->children('http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'); 
  if ($gd->rating) {
    $attrs = $gd->rating->attributes();
    $rating = $attrs['average']; 
  } else {
    $rating = 0; 
  } 

  echo "<li>\n";
  echo "<a href=\"{$watch}\">{$media->group->title}</a>
  <br/>\n";
  echo sprintf("%0.2f", $length/60) . " min. | {$rating} user rating
  <br/>\n";
  echo "{$media->group->description}<p/>\n";
  echo "<p/></li>\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get VideoID and then put it in iframe.
Here is the code:

```
<?php
$string = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoID&feature=youtube_gdata_player";

$startpoint=strpos($string,'watch?v=');$startpoint=$startpoint+8;
$length=strpos($string,'&');$length = $length - $startpoint;
$videoId =  substr($string,$startpoint,$length);
$ytstring = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$videoId.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
echo $videoId;
echo $ytstring;
?>
```

Comment: So I took a little of what you have here and got the video id so it links to the full screen embed now I just need to get it to echo target="video frame" in the <a> tag.  How would I go about doing this. it is in the last part of the code. Here echo "<a href=\"http://youtube.com/embed/{$videoId}\">{$media->group->title}</a>  After I can get that then it will be exacly what I need for some reason when I put in target="video-frame" into the code the server doesn't accept the page anymore.  Thanks for your help I really appreciate it.

Comment: I have also tried target=\"#video-frame\" but it just treats it as _blank

Comment: @user3331344 please clarify

Comment: @user3331344
target attribute of  a tag does not support "video frame"  
source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

You might need this:
<a target='_blank' href='http://youtube.com/embed'.$videoId.' > {$media->group->title}</a>

 please further clarify

Comment: Ya sorry so I want to target an iframe that is already on my page #video-frame.  Sorry i forgot to put the # in the comment above.  But when I put that into the php echo at the bottom of the script it just treats it like _blank and opens a new tab.  I would like for it to target the iframe that is already on my page or even better target a bootstrap modal that I have.  But whenever I put the code like follows:   echo "<a href=\"http://youtube.com/embed/{$videoId}\" target=\"#video-frame\">{$media->group->title}</a> it just goes to a different tab.

Comment: Is there a way to write target="#video-frame" in the echo or data-toggle="modal" and data-target="videoModal" with the php echo in the <a> tag

Comment: Ok so i figured it out had to put the name of the iframe so name="video-frame" and the echo as just target=\"video-frame\" now everthing works great thank you for your help I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend to go with JSON instead of XML feed. In order to accomplish loading videos into Iframe, you'll need to use Javascript.

Here's a quick demo you can use for reference:

```
 <?php 
//YouTube json feed example:
$keyword = "basketball";
$file = file_get_contents("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/$keyword?v=2&alt=json");

//decode into array
$decoded = json_decode($file, true);

//point the feed to 'entry' array
$entries = $decoded['feed']['entry'];

//parse through entries
if (!empty($entries)) {
    for($i=0; $i<count($entries); $i++) {
        $thumb = $entries[$i]['media$group']['media$thumbnail'][0]['url'];
        $title = $entries[$i]['title']['$t'];
        $description = $entries[$i]['media$group']['media$description']['$t'];
        $video = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/".$entries[$i]['media$group']['yt$videoid']['$t']."?wmode=opaque";
        $published = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($entries[$i]['published']['$t']));
        $content[]= "<a href=\"javascript:yt_load_video('$video');\"><img src=\"$thumb\"><br />$title</a><br /><small>$description<hr />$published</small>";
    }           
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function yt_load_video(url) {
    $("iframe").attr("src",url);
    return;
}
</script>

<?php if (!empty($content)) : ?>
    <iframe type="text/html" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $entries[0]['media$group']['yt$videoid']['$t']; ?>?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" width="400" height="300"></iframe>
    <hr />

    <?php foreach($content as $thumb) : ?>
        <div style="float:left; margin:4px; width:200px; height:200px; overflow:scroll"><?php echo $thumb ?></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Just curious what would I call to get the related videos instead of a playlist.  I can't find anything on it. I like that way this is set up better than what I am using but I would like to set the video and then get its related videos if that is possible.  And maybe a title for the thumnails.  I know that sounds like a lot but i figured I would ask because I like that way this is set up and do like the json format better, maybe if you could point me in the right direction I am new to using the youtube API.  Thanks

Comment: If nothing else I could just use the playlist for various things but it would still be nice to get the title to the thumbnails, I will mess with this some more and see if I can get it but just figured I would ask.  Thanks.

Comment: I edited the code to add the keyword search, title, description and published date.